# Sort float numbers List from small to large

Tags: c#, windows

I want to sort float numbers List from small to large. I tried to use the array.Sort () method but it doesn't work.
Below is my code.

```
 List<float> array = new List<float>();
      array.Add(x);
      listBox1.Items.Add(x);
```

Comment: Your code does not show the use of the `List<T>.Sort` method.  And fyi it's a bit odd to name a list variable `array`.

Comment: Wild guess: did you tell your listbox to sort alphabetically?

Comment: @KlausGütter no i didn't. How can I do it?

Comment: I have no clue whether your listbox is Winforms, WPF, UWP, Xamarin or...

Comment: @KlausGütter it's Winforms

Comment: The it would be the [Sorted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted) property. be sure it is *not* set

Comment: @KlausGütter Ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0):

```
List<float> array = new List<float>();

array.Add(x);

array.Sort();
```

When `array` (quite a *strange* name for `List<float>`) is sorted, we can *insert* `x` somewhere in the middle of `listBox1.Items`. Asuming that `listBox1.Items` contains ordered `float` items only, we can put

```
// Here's we have WinForms ListBox
int at = listBox1.Items.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; ++i) {
  if (x < (float) (listBox1.Items[i])) {
    at = i;

    break;
  }
}

listBox1.Items.Insert(at, x);
```

Comment: If you have a sorted list, you can simply assign it to the list box's data source: `listBox1.DataSource = array;`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Well, I will try that option too. Thanks!